# Event transparency for a part of the widget only

Tags: c++, qt, events, widget

The software shows 3 widgets:

- Main window
- Content widget, that cover most of the main window
- custom widget, that cover part of both, the main window and the content widget.

The custom widget has a part (defined as a `QRect`) that need to be `Event-opaque`, while the surrounding zone has to be `Event-transparent`.

I tried with:

```cpp
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
```

But all sub-widgets of custom become transparent also.

I also tried with `setMask`, but then the custom widget is unable to draw on the surrounding area.

How do I achieve this partial event-transparency?

Example (it does not explain the full problem, just add a base on which to test solutions):

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "transparentwidget.hpp"
#include "normalwidget.hpp"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Main Window
    NormalWidget window;
    window.resize(500,500);
    window.setObjectName("window");
    window.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,128,128); ");

    // Content window
    NormalWidget content(&window);
    content.setObjectName("content");
    content.resize(400, 400);
    content.move(0,0);
    content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(128,0,0,128);");

    TransparentWidget custom(&window);
    custom.setObjectName("custom");
    custom.resize(500, 200);
    custom.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0,128,0,128);");

    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

transparentwidget.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef TRANSPARENTWIDGET_H
#define TRANSPARENTWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>

// This widget shall be transparent in some parts
class TransparentWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TransparentWidget(QWidget *parent = 0): QWidget(parent)
    {
        // Start of solution with WA_TransparentForMouseEvents (not working)
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
        // end solution with WA_TransparentForMouseEvents
    }
    ~TransparentWidget(){}

protected:
    QRect opaqueRect = QRect(0,0,400,100);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        // Solution with setMask, not working
        QRegion reg(opaqueRect);
        setMask(reg);
        // end of setMask solution
        
        QStyleOption opt;
        opt.init(this);
        QPainter p(this);
        style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
    }

    bool event(QEvent *event)
    {
        // Starting of solution with event propagation (not working)
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress ||
            event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            QMouseEvent* e = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if (e && !opaqueRect.contains(e->pos()) return false;
        }
        // end solution with event propagation.

        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) qDebug() << "Press: " << objectName();
        else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) qDebug() << "Release: " << objectName();
        
        return QWidget::event(event);
    }
};
#endif
```

normalwidget.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef NORMALWIDGET_H
#define NORMALWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>

// Widgets that are not event-transparent
class NormalWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NormalWidget(QWidget *parent = 0): QWidget(parent){}
    ~NormalWidget(){}

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QStyleOption opt;
        opt.init(this);
        QPainter p(this);
        style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
    }

    bool event(QEvent *event)
    {
        
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) qDebug() << "Press: " << objectName();
        else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) qDebug() << "Release: " << objectName();

    }
};

#endif // NORMALWIDGET_H
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the docs say:

> When enabled, this attribute disables the delivery of mouse events to
>   the widget and **its children**.

The solution is to ignore all the mouse events inside `TransparentWidget::event()`. If you do a mouse event over a child of `TransparentWidget`, the event will be consumed by the child, otherwise it will be delivered to the parent of `TransparentWidget`:

```
bool TransparentWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress ||
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease ||
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        return false;
    else
        return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

Comment: Your "TransparentWidget" is not transparent but only with his parent widget. In my scenario, the "Content" widget do not get event trough the "custom" widget.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I didn't mean that all widgets have to inherit from `TransparentWidget`, but only the "custom" one. Thus all the sub-widgets (did you mean children?) of custom widget will receive events as normal, but clicking on the custom widget directly will send the event to the Main window instead, bypassing the Content widget.

Comment: If the custom widget is handled before the content widget, you could accept() the event and send a newly created copy of the event to the main window with postEvent(). I would also check in the events for the content widget if the click happened to be in the custom widgets geometry() and ignore() the event if so.

Comment: The custom element do not know which is the "content" widget below it, and the first shared parent shall remove the duplicated event. That is not a viable solution.